# Html Form Action; are HTML tags added to the url page?

Tags: html, tags

You know how in HTML you have input forms specifying the action:

```
<form action="example.php" method="get">
First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

That will link to example.php when the form is submitted. My question is, does the resulting webpage have html tags added to it, like so:

```
<html>
<body>
example.php
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: all my what? are you asking if the html is altered in the div heiarchy - that is only the DOM is updated? if that is your question, then the answer is no. the page is redirected to a different page which is exactly what you make it in example.php. now of course there are ways to do this, using ajax, but thats a different question.

Comment: My question is what happens when the form action is completed. Is the example.php just dumped onto the returned webpage? With no extraneous HTML tags attached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just redirects to the given page (no HTML is added) as you already said, passing the post/get variables in the URL. So by submitting in the URL you'll have something like :

```
example.php?fname=Name&lname=LastName
```

This is used for further processing by the `$_GET[]` or `$_POST[]` PHP methods.

Comment: And I ask this question because I remember having a PHP script that printed out a table in html, and I didn't include HTML tags.

Comment: Maybe it was just printing it if some parameter is provided, can't tell you without looking at the code. :) You can check this -> http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-post.html

Answer (score 0):

You can access your form elements from example.php by GET and POST variables. Example:

$fname = $_GET['fname'];
$lname = $_GET['lname'];

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an ajax solution such as jquery library, you can write your php in a way it returns just the code you want to put at the calling webpage, using a div container to receive and show the returned content.

Otherwise, your php script must return a complete html code with all sort of  opening and closing tags.